# ngStyle not getting applied

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my angular 5 app, [ngStyle] is not expanding to style attribute. I only see ng-reflect-ng-style.  This used to work before. Did something change in the recent updates to Angular or Angular-cli?

This is template:

```
<div *ngIf="ready" class="card" [ngStyle]="dimensions">
</div
```

This is the generated HTML:

```
<div _ngcontent-c6="" class="card ng-tns-c6-1" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]">

</div>
```

Expected, with dimensions = {width: '240px'}:

```
<div _ngcontent-c6="" class="card ng-tns-c6-1" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="width:240px">

</div>
```

Comment: Please reproduce it. It works well for me

Answer (score 11):

You can use it in directly template-

```
[ngStyle]="{'width.px': 200}"
```

or

```
dimensions = {'width.px': 200};
<div *ngIf="ready" class="card" [ngStyle]="dimensions">
</div
```

Comment: for angular 15 use [style] instead of [ngStyle]

Answer (score 2):

You can try as below as well:

```
<div *ngIf="ready" class="card" [ngStyle]="setStyles()">
</div>

public setStyles(): any {
    let styles = {            
        'width': '200px'
    };      
    return styles;
}
```

**OR**

```
[ngStyle]="{'width': '200px'}"
```

Comment: Function call from template can lead to performance issues on large scale UIs

Answer (score 2):

As of today & with Angular > 11, you have to sanitize such information like the following

```html
<div [attr.style]="dimensions | safeStyle"> </div>
```

Were `safeStyle` is

```js
@Pipe({ name: 'safeStyle' })
export class SafeStylePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value)
  }
}
```

*Found the solution on [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12009#issuecomment-482003167)*

Comment: This seems to be necessary only if you have to use "!important". It's was made my code not work, thank you for the link ! I was going crazy.